# Is there a way to return a new object each time with EasyMock return anyTimes()?

Tags: java, powermock, easymock

I'm working on a unit test for a class that relies heavily on Calendar. I'm trying to mock out all the calls so that I can basically insert my own specified system time into the class to do some date-time logic testing.

This is my first attempt:

```
Calendar fixedSystemCal = Calendar.getInstance();
fixedSystemCal.set(2021, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 22, 18, 0, 0);

PowerMock.mockStatic(Calendar.class);
EasyMock.expect(Calendar.getInstance()).andReturn(fixedSystemCal).anyTimes();
PowerMock.replay();
```

Unfortunately, after some poking around, I discovered that this doesn't work, because the calendar object is mutated inside the class. Since this mock returns the same calendar each time, this is a problem. For example:

```
Calendar firstCall = Calendar.getInstance(); //Feb 22
firstCall.add(Calendar.DATE, 5); //Feb 27

Calendar secondCall = Calendar.getInstance() // This is also Feb 27 now
```

Is there any way to get a different calendar object back each time (for an arbitrary number of calls)? The only solution I've found so far is just repeating it many times like this:

```
Calendar fixedSystemCal = Calendar.getInstance();
fixedSystemCal.set(2021, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 22, 18, 0, 0);

PowerMock.mockStatic(Calendar.class);
EasyMock.expect(Calendar.getInstance()).andReturn((Calendar) fixedSystemCal.clone()).andReturn((Calendar) fixedSystemCal.clone()).andReturn((Calendar) fixedSystemCal.clone());
PowerMock.replay();
```

I'm going to be replacing this code with Java time in the next step but I need a functioning unit test before I can make the change over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `andAnswer` instead of `andReturn` to provide a lambda/`IAnswer` implementation that you can use to return a new instance.  Something like:

```
EasyMock.expect(Calendar.getInstance())
   .andAnswer(() -> (Calendar)fixedSystemCal.clone());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `andAnswer` instead of `andReturn`. Though they might seem similar with their name, both serve a different purpose during mocking and testing. If you need work with static values (always same instance), use andReturn. If you need to use dynamic or derived values, use andAnswer.

### Code Example

```
Calendar fixedSystemCal = Calendar.getInstance();
fixedSystemCal.set(2021, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 22, 18, 0, 0);

PowerMock.mockStatic(Calendar.class);
EasyMock.expect(Calendar.getInstance()).andReturn((Calendar) fixedSystemCal.clone()).andReturn((Calendar) fixedSystemCal.clone()).andReturn((Calendar) fixedSystemCal.clone());
PowerMock.replay();

EasyMock.expect(Calendar.getInstance()).andAnswer(() -> (Calendar) fixedSystemCal.clone());
```

### andReturn

`andReturn` sets a value to be returned when the method is called. This value will **always** be the **same instance** that you defined. In your case, it will return the value of `fixedSystemCal.clone()`, which will always be the same instance of the calendar you cloned once. Think of it as saving that clone in a variable, and always returning that same variable when the method is called.

You only should use andReturn when you know the return value at the time you mock a method call. This predefined value will then be returned when you invoke the mocked method.

If you want this represented in regular code. Mocking a method `getDate` would look something like this, where you always return the same instance of calendar:

```
private Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

public Calendar getCalendar() {
    return calendar;
}
```

### andAnwser

`andAnwser` will perform a method before returning the value. This can be used when you need to do **additional actions** when a mocked method is invoked, e.g. when you need to clone an object or you want to perform some logic based on the arguments that were passed.

If you want this represented in regular code. Mocking a method `getDate` would look something like this, where you always return a new instance of Calendar:

```
public Calendar getCalendar() {
    return Calendar.getInstance();
}
```